# Cause of selected [ArcSDE 10] feature dataset does not contain any feature classes which can participate in topology?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, enterprise-geodatabase, topology

When trying to create a topology for a polygon feature class in ArcSDE 10.  I right click the feature dataset that the feature class resides and try to create a new topology.  I get an error saying, "The selected feature dataset does not contain any feature classes which can participate in a topology".

The feature class I am targeting has a z value.

Would this be the culprit?

Answer (score 5):

We had a similar problem a few weeks ago - as Fezter said, you will need to unregister your dataset as versioned. The resource centre lists the steps [here.](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//006200000009000000.htm) A word of caution - make sure that all of your versions have been reconciled and posted against default, and not just to your QA version or anything in between. We learnt this the hard way!

Answer (score 2):

I found [this article](http://support.esri.com/en/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/23873) on the ESRI knowledge base.  You may need to unregister your feature class.

Answer (score 0):

Working with topology in versioned geodatabases is relatively straightforward. But first, you need to understand some version-based workflows and the behavior of topology in a versioned environment.

[image]