# Cannot Create Topology in SDE

Tags: enterprise-geodatabase, topology, feature-dataset

I am trying create a topology for a zoning dataset in my SDE feature dataset. I've run into a few issues. First off was an issue with versioning that this questions resolved: [How to solve "Cannot create topology" in ArcCatalog?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/46703/how-to-solve-cannot-create-topology-in-arccatalog)

Now I've run into a second (well more like fifth) issue concerning the spatial references of the Topology / Zoning dataset:

[image: SDE Topology Error]

The feature dataset has the pre-defined projection we use for all our data. In terms of spatial references, all layers within the feature dataset are governed by the spatial reference / projection of the feature dataset correct?